# DB manager in QGIS 2.0 UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I followed this post:[pgRouting 2.0 for Windows quick guide](http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/), and I want to use DB manager to load the test data into my PostgreSQL database.

I used url to get the test data:[image]

I have set up the connection to my PostgreSQL 9.2, like this:[image]

and the connection is fine, but as I fire up my DB manager, trying to connect to PostGIS, I got those errors:(errors got as I double clicked "PostgreSQL 9.2")

[image]

```
執行Python程式碼時發生錯誤:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 404, in rowCount
    self._refreshIndex( parent, True )
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 456, in _refreshIndex
    if item.populate():
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 151, in populate
    if not connection.connect():
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 100, in connect
    return self.connectToUri(uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 93, in connectToUri
    self.db = self.databasesFactory( self, uri )
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 67, in databasesFactory
    return PGDatabase(connection, uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 134, in **init**
    Database.**init**(self, connection, uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 172, in **init**
    self.connector = self.connectorsFactory( uri )
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 137, in connectorsFactory
    return PostGisDBConnector(uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\connector.py", line 57, in **init**
    raise ConnectionError(e)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 40, in **init**
    msg = unicode( msg, 'utf-8' )
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Python 版本:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS 版本:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, d94c044

Python 路徑: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\Users\Heinz/.qgis2/python', 'C:\Users\Heinz/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Did I make some mistake in my process?

I am working under Windows 8.1, QGIS 2.0, PostgreSQL 9.2

Answer (score 1):

As this message show:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

It is likely due a problem with character encodings. Maybe your database is using ASCII instead of UTF8.

To check what character encoding is using your database, you cold ask your postgreSQL server with *PGAdmin III* or *psql*.

If you have **PGAdmin III**, you could check the encoding used by the *postgis20* database by:

1. clicking the database. In my example, the database is named *sig*. You have to find *postgis20*.
2. Looking at the properties of that database and finding the *Encoding* property. It should be an encoding adequate for your language and the same QGIS is using. I bet it is ASCII. You should be UTF8 (there are many other options, but all the people should be using UTF8).

[image: encoding property of a database. PostgreSQL]

If you prefer *psql*, you could ask **PostgreSQL** with the psql commad **\l**:

```
postgres=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 sig       | usr_sig  | UTF8      | C       | C     | =Tc/usr_sig          +
           |          |           |         |       | usr_sig=CTc/usr_sig  +
           |          |           |         |       | sys_sig=CTc/usr_sig
 template0 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=#
```

In this case, you can see my *sig* database use *UTF8* encoding.

If your database *postgis20* is using *SQL_ASCII* you are in trouble. It is possible it happened because the *template1* database is with *SQL_ASCII* encoding. When you create a new database, PostgreSQL use the database *template1* as a template by default.

Conclusion: The next time, create the database with *UTF8*. How to do it?

1. If your *template1* database has already encoding *UTF8*, then simply run as the root user of your PostgreSQL (typically *postgres*):

   $ createdb postgis20
2. If your *template1* has encoding *SQL_ASCII* the run:

   $ createdb --encoding=UTF8 --template=template0

When you want PostgreSQL use no template while creating a new database, you specify the database *template0* as the template. PostgreSQL will ignore it.